# Do i need to call Page.IsValid explicitly if i am using Asp.net valdiators?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have used Asp.net validation controls like Required Field Validator etc so do i need to explicitly mention Page.IsValid or is it called by default ?

```
<label>DeadLine</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDeadLine" runat="server" CssClass="textField_width"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtDeadLine" ErrorMessage="Deadline Date is Required" 
                        ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="GroupComposeLetter">Deadline Date is Required
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
 <%--<asp:GridView ID="gridViewComplaints" runat="server"

     ></asp:GridView>--%>
<br />
```

Answer (score 3):

If the control has `CausesValidation` set to `true` (default) it is not needed.

Controls where this is set by default:

- `Button`,
- `ImageButton`,
- `LinkButton`
- Web server controls,
- `HtmlInputButton`,
- `HtmlInputImage`,
- `HtmlButton`
- HTML server controls,
- controls that can automatically post back to the server such as the `TextBox`, `CheckBox`, `ListControl`, and `BulletedList`

So if you've set it to `false` you could force validation on serverside by calling `Page.Validate(ValidationGroupName)` manually. Afterwards you can check `Page.IsValid`.

Comment: ok but quoting your last sentence, Why would someone do that ? disabling and then calling in server ?

Comment: @user3518032: sometimes you don't want to force validation on clientside always but under certain conditions that are known on serverside. Or you want to combine multiple validation-groups.

Answer (score 0):

> Validation occurs after Page_Load, but before event handlers (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=VS.100).aspx).

---

> If your button does not cause validation, you must manually fire Page.Validate.

- (**Page.Validate** method is fired automatically by controls that have the CausesValidation property set to true(Which is default value for Button control).
- **Page.IsValid property** tells you whether the validation succeeded or not.)

  More details, please see this discussion

[How does Page.IsValid work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762467/how-does-page-isvalid-work)